# mysqli_real_escape_string doesn't work with list() and explode() function

Tags: php, mysql, list, explode

I use this line of code:

```
list($variable1, $variable2) = explode("|", $_POST['something']);
```

and after that, when I put both variables into mysqli_real_escape_string:

```
$variable1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $variable1);
$variable2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $variable2);
```

it doesn't work. I know this because double quotation marks won't insert into mysql database. Where am I wrong?

Comment: Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: Why are you using `@variable` instead of `$variable`?

Comment: You shouldn't be using `mysqli_real_escape_string` anymore, it's not safe.  You should be using prepared statements: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: _it doesn't work._ So it smokes, catches fire, what?

Comment: I am using $variable, @ it's a typo, sorry about that. I know about prepare, but before I learn that, I need this. If I insert "something" it won't work...

Comment: Preparing statements are actually a whole lot easier than using mysqli_real_escape_string. You'll never have to worry about quoting your variables again, which eliminates a whole lot of syntax errors.

Comment: So, how prepare statements suppose to look for this?

Answer (score 0):

> @variable1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $variable1);

This code is not working at all. Syntax `@variable1` is invalid. It should be

```
$variable1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $variable1);
```

Comment: Let's not teach/propagate sloppy and dangerous coding practices. If you post an answer without prepared statements [you may want to consider this before posting](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/344703/). Additionally [a more valuable answer comes from showing the OP the right method](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/290789/1011527).

Comment: This is not about any practices but proper elementary syntax issue OP is having. I believe your comment here and under the question flags the dangers sufficiently.

Answer (score 0):

You could use code below, or you can use a foreach loop to assign a variable to every existing key/value pair in the array.

```
$clean_post = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['something']);
$array_post = explode("|", $clean_post);
$value1 = $array_post[0];
$value2 = $array_post[1];
```

Comment: I now realize that mysqli_real_escape_string is not a problem why I can't insert text with double quotes into mysql database. Probel is definitly into this code:

list($variable1, $variable2) = explode("|", $_POST['something']);

but I can't find solution.